# Get the first object in an array of objects who matches the condition

Tags: javascript, json

I have this array of objects

```
[{},{"IGG":"\n1000400078","Date effet":"16/04/2007","Statut déontologie":"A","Version charte":"1","N°Charte":"0","Nom charte":"Non exposé","Statut Charte":"A","Date envoi charte":"","Dat 1er relance":"","Date 2eme relance":"","Date 3 eme relance":"","Date de validation":""},{"IGG":""},{"IGG":"\n1000400103","Date effet":"23/05/2016","Statut déontologie":"A","Version charte":"2","N°Charte":"1","Nom charte":"Régime Général","Statut Charte":"A","Date envoi charte":"27/09/2010","Dat 1er relance":"07/10/2010","Date 2eme relance":"18/10/2010","Date 3 eme relance":"28/10/2010","Date de validation":"20/11/2015"},{},{"IGG":"\n1000400381","Date effet":"04/09/2019","Statut déontologie":"A","Version charte":"2","N°Charte":"3","Nom charte":"Initié Société Générale","Statut Charte":"A","Date envoi charte":"16/09/2019","Dat 1er relance":"26/09/2019","Date 2eme relance":"","Date 3 eme relance":"","Date de validation":"27/09/2019"},{},{"IGG":"\n1000401040","Date effet":"01/09/2015","Statut déontologie":"A","Version charte":"2","N°Charte":"5","Nom charte":"Régime Général & Initié Société Générale","Statut Charte":"A","Date envoi charte":"03/09/2015","Dat 1er relance":"14/09/2015","Date 2eme relance":"","Date 3 eme relance":"","Date de validation":"18/09/2015"},{},{"IGG":"\n1007829487","Date effet":"03/12/2019","Statut déontologie":"A","Version charte":"1","N°Charte":"8","Nom charte":"Conseiller Gestion Patrimoine","Statut Charte":"A","Date envoi charte":"13/12/2019","Dat 1er relance":"23/12/2019","Date 2eme relance":"02/01/2020","Date 3 eme relance":"13/01/2020","Date de validation":"14/01/2020"},{},{"IGG":"\n"}]
```

and I want to get the object which has an IGG value including the IGG in URL query parameter

For example if I go on localhost:8000/igg?igg=1000400078, I need to get the object which has "IGG": \n1000400078", so this object :

```
{"IGG":"\n1000400078","Date effet":"16/04/2007","Statut déontologie":"A","Version charte":"1","N°Charte":"0","Nom charte":"Non exposé","Statut Charte":"A","Date envoi charte":"","Dat 1er relance":"","Date 2eme relance":"","Date 3 eme relance":"","Date de validation":""}
```

So I tried :

```
json.find(item => i.includes(item.IGG);
```

But it returns

```
[{"IGG":""}]
```

Can somebody help me please

Comment: What's the value of `i`?

Comment: i is equal to the query in URL ! (if you're on localhost:8000/igg?igg=5, then i = 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `includes` test is backwards, it should be `item.IGG.includes(i)`.

You also need to check that `item.IGG` exists, otherwise you'll get an error trying to call `.includes()` on `undefined`.

```js
const json = [{},{"IGG":"\n1000400078","Date effet":"16/04/2007","Statut déontologie":"A","Version charte":"1","N°Charte":"0","Nom charte":"Non exposé","Statut Charte":"A","Date envoi charte":"","Dat 1er relance":"","Date 2eme relance":"","Date 3 eme relance":"","Date de validation":""},{"IGG":""},{"IGG":"\n1000400103","Date effet":"23/05/2016","Statut déontologie":"A","Version charte":"2","N°Charte":"1","Nom charte":"Régime Général","Statut Charte":"A","Date envoi charte":"27/09/2010","Dat 1er relance":"07/10/2010","Date 2eme relance":"18/10/2010","Date 3 eme relance":"28/10/2010","Date de validation":"20/11/2015"},{},{"IGG":"\n1000400381","Date effet":"04/09/2019","Statut déontologie":"A","Version charte":"2","N°Charte":"3","Nom charte":"Initié Société Générale","Statut Charte":"A","Date envoi charte":"16/09/2019","Dat 1er relance":"26/09/2019","Date 2eme relance":"","Date 3 eme relance":"","Date de validation":"27/09/2019"},{},{"IGG":"\n1000401040","Date effet":"01/09/2015","Statut déontologie":"A","Version charte":"2","N°Charte":"5","Nom charte":"Régime Général & Initié Société Générale","Statut Charte":"A","Date envoi charte":"03/09/2015","Dat 1er relance":"14/09/2015","Date 2eme relance":"","Date 3 eme relance":"","Date de validation":"18/09/2015"},{},{"IGG":"\n1007829487","Date effet":"03/12/2019","Statut déontologie":"A","Version charte":"1","N°Charte":"8","Nom charte":"Conseiller Gestion Patrimoine","Statut Charte":"A","Date envoi charte":"13/12/2019","Dat 1er relance":"23/12/2019","Date 2eme relance":"02/01/2020","Date 3 eme relance":"13/01/2020","Date de validation":"14/01/2020"},{},{"IGG":"\n"}]
let i = "1000400078";
console.log(json.find(item => item.IGG && item.IGG.includes(i)));
```

Comment: this answer is wrong! has nothing to do with url location and `includes` is not good for perfect matches... since it returns true if `a` is substring of `b`. :-|

Comment: I assumed that the URL parameter was already extracted into the variable `i`. And a substring is needed because `item.IGG` begins with newline. Although it could also be done by stripping the newline and then doing an exact comparison.

Answer (score 2):

You have to compare with the url in your browser, so use `location`

```
const data = [{}, {"IGG":"\n1000400078","Date effet":"16/04/2007","Statut déontologie":"A","Version charte":"1","N°Charte":"0","Nom charte":"Non exposé","Statut Charte":"A","Date envoi charte":"","Dat 1er relance":"","Date 2eme relance":"","Date 3 eme relance":"","Date de validation":""},{"IGG":""},{"IGG":"\n1000400103","Date effet":"23/05/2016","Statut déontologie":"A","Version charte":"2","N°Charte":"1","Nom charte":"Régime Général","Statut Charte":"A","Date envoi charte":"27/09/2010","Dat 1er relance":"07/10/2010","Date 2eme relance":"18/10/2010","Date 3 eme relance":"28/10/2010","Date de validation":"20/11/2015"},{},{"IGG":"\n1000400381","Date effet":"04/09/2019","Statut déontologie":"A","Version charte":"2","N°Charte":"3","Nom charte":"Initié Société Générale","Statut Charte":"A","Date envoi charte":"16/09/2019","Dat 1er relance":"26/09/2019","Date 2eme relance":"","Date 3 eme relance":"","Date de validation":"27/09/2019"},{},{"IGG":"\n1000401040","Date effet":"01/09/2015","Statut déontologie":"A","Version charte":"2","N°Charte":"5","Nom charte":"Régime Général & Initié Société Générale","Statut Charte":"A","Date envoi charte":"03/09/2015","Dat 1er relance":"14/09/2015","Date 2eme relance":"","Date 3 eme relance":"","Date de validation":"18/09/2015"},{},{"IGG":"\n1007829487","Date effet":"03/12/2019","Statut déontologie":"A","Version charte":"1","N°Charte":"8","Nom charte":"Conseiller Gestion Patrimoine","Statut Charte":"A","Date envoi charte":"13/12/2019","Dat 1er relance":"23/12/2019","Date 2eme relance":"02/01/2020","Date 3 eme relance":"13/01/2020","Date de validation":"14/01/2020"},{},{"IGG":"\n"}]

const result = data.find(item => item.IGG.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, '') === location.search.split('igg=')[1]);

console.log(result);
```